# Type alias circularly references itself - parsing expressions

Tags: typescript, types

I was writing a parser parsing expressions and defined these types:

```
export type ExpressionType = AdditiveExpressionType;

export type AdditiveExpressionType =
  | MultiplicativeExpressionType
  | {
      type: string;
      operator: string;
      left: AdditiveExpressionType | MultiplicativeExpressionType;
      right: MultiplicativeExpressionType;
    };

export type MultiplicativeExpressionType =
  | PrimaryExpressionType
  | {
      type: string;
      operator: string;
      left: MultiplicativeExpressionType | PrimaryExpressionType;
      right: PrimaryExpressionType;
    };

export type PrimaryExpressionType = LiteralType | ParenthesizedExpressionType;

export type ParenthesizedExpressionType = LiteralType | ExpressionType;

export type LiteralType = StringLiteralType | NumericLiteralType;

export type StringLiteralType = { type: string; value: string };

export type NumericLiteralType = { type: string; value: number };
```

However I got errors: Type alias circularly references itself because ParenthesizedExpressionType can be another ExpressionType. How should avoid this circular reference error?

Comment: Well, you have to break the circularity; you can't write `type A = {} | A`. Saying `ParenthesizedExpressionType` can be "another" `ExpressionType` is confusing to me, I'm not sure how you could even parse something this way. Surely this boils down to "a `ParenthesizedExpressionType` can be this or that or the other thing *or a `ParenthesizedExpressionType`*" which is circular and seems like it couldn't map onto anything you could implement.

Comment: If you just write "this or that or the other thing" you get something non-circular, like [this](//tsplay.dev/wRRKXw).  But is that what you want?  I have no idea because the use case isn't clear to me (these might as well be `Foo` and `Bar` for all the context I have).

Comment: Thank you! I think I get the idea of breaking the circularity. I was confused at first because my code was recursive - thought type need to be recursive as well, but it turned out type need to be flattened.